# Encryption & Decryption of Mysql data through Java or extra layers

Tags: java, php, mysql

In my project portal I have already added multiple project of Java and PHP which are pointing to Same mysql server. Now I have a requirement for security purpose that I have to encrypt the data that are stored in mysql.

So, the hectic way is to encrypt the data in Java/PHP side and store it to the server or use Encryption provided by mysql in every CRUD operations.

But as I said we have multiple projects and doing this activity will be time consuming. So, my questions are.

1) Is mysql provide any service where the stored data will be encrypt/decrypt automatically without any intervention.

2) IS that possible to design any middle layer through which all the DB request will pass and it will automatically encrypt/decrypt the data.

Let me know if anymore clarification required. I am really looking for some guidance from here.

Also note that the data moved from UI to database and also stores as plain text for now.

Comment: Use https protocol: TLS/SSL

Comment: you need to improve this question to understand what state the data is in during its flow from end-to-end